# Why is my website working with Safari, but not FireFox or IE?

Tags: javascript, css, html, firefox, safari

I'm making a simple site for a small photography business. Everything's going well until I test in Firefox. I notice it totally doesn't work.
You'll find the website [here](http://www.jeffreyaphoto.com/).

I have an image map on top of text and an image. When you click in a certain area in the image map, it'll change the left frame based on where you clicked. Problem is in Firefox, it ain't working. I have all the CSS and Javascript inside the index page. Can anyone help me with getting this working universally?

And if it seems my code is amateurish, that's likely because I haven't much experience in a professional setting.

Comment: Kind of off topic, but you should seriously consider using a CMS. Wordpress, Joomla, or Drupal are great. You can do them totally free and most hosts handle the install for you. Though, paid themes are usually alot better.

Comment: If you want code that works decently in all browsers, you have to follow the coding standard.  Validate your HTML at the W3C and fix all errors.  You will also learn a lot in the process.  See:  http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jeffreyaphoto.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not specified a doctype .. this will trigger IE to go into render your page in [Quirks Mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html)

To prevent that, include a doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of your file and make sure there are no comments or white space preceding it.

Comment: Well as lmortenson mentioned, the forward slash worked for the linkage, but there's still the issue of the clickable imagemap not working in Firefox.

Comment: Freaking yes. Only issue now is the blue border around the imagemap in IE. Except the <!DOCTYPE html> tends to cause the imagemap to go to point (0,0) within the table.

Comment: Thanks man! You and Sparky up there saved me. My website is now HTML5 compliant. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

The slashes in your iframe `src` aren't forward slashes, they are backslashes.  Switch them to forward slashes and your iframes will start showing up.

Here's someone with the same issue: http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/737230

> I had the same problem. My iFrames worked in IE and Chrome but not
>   Firefox. Changed the slashes from slash to forward slash and all is now
>   working. This one did not work in FF

```
 <IFRAME src="\myride\TheRider\index.html" width="640" height="640" 
    frameborder="no"></IFRAME>
```

> This one works great!

```
<IFRAME src="/myride/TheRider/index.html" width="640" height="640" 
    frameborder="no"></IFRAME>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another reason why firefox may not show iframe content is the URL referenced in an iframe will be blocked if the page you are on is https but the referenced page inside the iframe is just http.